# Which list type to use?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, arraylist, checkboxlist

I was using Dictionary in order to add some data and later bind it to ChecBoxListControl, but I got a major issue when I get 2 keys with the same value. Dictionary can not take 2 keys with the same value.

So, now I am wondering what I could use instead of Dictionary which would give me the "same experience" as Dictionary with key and value.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: If you have two keys that have the same key name and value, why do you need to add it twice? How would you select which one to use later?

Comment: you could make a ````List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>````, but you lose the ability to lookup the values by key in constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` or a [`ListItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You say you want a collection which duplicated Keys. It's not possible, because in their usage, `collection[key]` returns a `TElement`.

A list to do what you want would have to return an `IEnumerable<TElement>` to represent all elements under that key.

It's possible to simulate that using `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` or an `List<Tuple<Item1, Item1>>`.

It won't have the syntactic sugar of using `collection[key]`, but it's close to what you want. And it's a lot less hurdle than implementing your own type.